# If $f$ is continuous then $f(B_r(a))\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-verification

I would appreciate if my proof could be reviewed for its correctness. And if you could please help with the *Case (ii)* below.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a continuous function. Prove that $f(B_r(a))$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ for all $r>0$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}^m$.

> Proof:
>
> Since $f$ is continuous, $\forall\epsilon>0, \exists r>0$ such that $x\in B_r(a) \implies f(x)\in B_\epsilon(f(a))$.
>
> *Case (i)*: $B_r(a)\subset f^{-1}(B_\epsilon(f(a)))$. Then $f(B_r(a))\subset B_\epsilon(f(a))$. So $f(B_r(a))$ is bounded.
>
> *Case (ii)*: $f^{-1}(B_\epsilon(f(a)))\subset B_r(a)$. Then $B_\epsilon(f(a))\subset f(B_r(a))$. [...]

Answer (score 0):

If you use the definition of continuity, the definition tells you that there exists some $r$ such that something happens with $B_r(0)$.

But you need to show that the statement is true for all $r$.

Also, if you have two sets, there is a third option: neither is contained in the other.

**Hint** Since $f$ is continuous, it is bounded on every **closed** ball.

Comment: Please let me know if this appears to be correct. Consider $\overline{B_r(a)}$, which is closed and bounded, and hence compact (by Heine-Borel). Since $f$ is continuous, $f(\overline{B_r(a)})$ is also compact. But this implies that $f(B_r(a))$ is bounded, since $f(\overline{B_r(a)}=f(B_r(a))\cup f(\partial B_r(a))$. @N.S.